# Derivative of delta function with respect to first argument

Tags: quantum-mechanics, differentiation, dirac-delta-distributions

In Shankar's QM book pg. 61, the derivative of the delta function $\delta(x-x')$ with respect to the first argument is
$$\delta'(x-x')=\frac{d}{dx}\delta(x-x')=-\frac{d}{dx'}\delta(x-x').$$

I tried verifying it myself using the chain rule:
$$\delta'(x-x')=\frac{d}{dx}\delta(x-x')= \frac{d(x-x')}{dx} \frac{d}{d(x-x')} \delta(x-x')=1\times\frac{d}{d(x-x')} \delta(x-x').$$

How do I proceed further to get $\delta'(x-x')=-\frac{d}{dx'}\delta(x-x')?$

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a big deal:
$$\frac{d}{dx^\prime}\delta(x-x^\prime)=\frac{d(x-x^\prime)}{dx^\prime}\frac{d}{d(x-x^\prime)}\delta(x-x^\prime)=-1\times \delta^\prime(x-x^\prime)$$

Answer (score 2):

For a careful approach, notation wise, I would suggest performing this computation as the following:

$$
\delta(x-x') = \delta \, \left[ \, g(x,x') \, \right] \; ,
$$

where $g(x,x') = x - x'$. $\,$ Then, the derivative will be:

$$
\left\{ \delta \left[ \, g(x,x') \, \right] \right\}^{(1)} = 
\delta\,^{(1)} \left[ \, g(x,x') \, \right] \; g^{(1)}(x,x')  \; ,
$$

now, it is very clear that there are two choices for the derivative of
$\,g\,(x,x')$, this avoids possible confusions.
Finally:

$$
\Rightarrow \;
\frac{d}{dx'} \, \delta \,(x-x') \; \frac{d}{dx'}(x-x')
=
(-1) \times\frac{d}{dx'} \, \delta \,(x-x') \; .
$$

Comment: I think your $\frac{d}{dx'}\delta$ should be replaced with $\delta'$ to make it clear that order of operation wise it's just the derivative of the delta function and that you don't need to apply the chain rule (again) to it. But maybe I'm just unfamiliar with the notation style you're using.

Comment: I was avoiding using $\delta'$ to leave the $'$ for the $x'$ only. But I made some changes to the answer.